# Difference between brk and sbrk

Tags: c, unix

I new to this can any one tell the exact difference between `brk` and `sbrk` with a brief example ? is there any efficiency factor to choose from any of the two?
`malloc` and `new` internally call `brk` or `sbrk`.

Answer (score 12):

```
int brk(void *addr);
```

> brk() sets the end of the data segment to the value specified by
>          addr, when that value is reasonable, the system has enough memory,
>          and the process does not exceed its maximum data size.
>
> On success, brk() returns zero.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno
>          is set to ENOMEM.

```
void *sbrk(intptr_t increment);
```

> sbrk() increments the program's data space by increment bytes.
>          Calling sbrk() with an increment of 0 can be used to find the current
>          location of the program break.
>
> On success, sbrk() returns the previous program break.  (If the break
>          was increased, then this value is a pointer to the start of the newly
>          allocated memory).  On error, (void *) -1 is returned, and errno is
>          set to ENOMEM.

[From linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html)

Answer (score 8):

`brk` sets the upper limit of the data segment, `sbrk` increments it. In ancient Unixes `malloc/free` used `sbrk`. On modern ones things could be very different, for example, OSX does not use `brk/sbrk` to manage heap allocations but `mmap`, `brk/sbrk` exist but are just emulation in a small segment of memory. This is almost the same on Linux (source code of mention the history of transition from brk/sbrk to mmap).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.Still little bit confused ,when a process is created data segment is fixed to some limit.suppose data segment has size of N brk can set the upper limit with in the the size of N or brk can set upper limit greater than the size N.sbrk increment  data segment size if so where heap allocation happen. thanks in advance

Comment: Upper limit is a..limit. A start there is basically no heap so data segment is reduce to some minimum, you can make it grows by allocation (brk/sbrk or whatever) but up to the limit. You can change the limit on some systems, but it is not the purpose of brk/sbrk. Heap is the way data segment is managed (allocation and holes are all in data segment).